# What is section_type: general processor error

Tags: kernel, cpu, hardware

In my server, I saw this:

```
BERT: Error records from previous boot:
[Hardware Error]: event severity: fatal
[Hardware Error]:  Error 0, type: fatal
[Hardware Error]:   section_type: general processor error
```

I don't know what does that mean 'general processor error'

I checked

https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6_2_B_final_Jan30.pdf

I still don't know what does that mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret those messages as: "During previous boot, some kind of processor error happened and it was a fatal error." In other words, this message was probably generated when booting the server after a system crash.

This would be your cue to check any vendor-specific hardware log viewing tools or similar: these might be able to provide as detailed information as possible.

Comment: why processor will happen error?